# How to redirect users to one site only temporarily on a multiple language site?

Tags: variations

I have a multilingual site which contains: English, Dutch and French.

Only Dutch language is ready at the moment. How can I prevent users with English and French language browser settings to access these two languages?
I would like the user to see only the Dutch version at the moment despite their browser language.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running variations?

Comment: yes. I am using variations.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps just change the welcome page for the english and french variation target sites. Add a content editor web part with a small script where you just change the window.location to the dutch site. Would suffice for a temporary change I guess.

As long as this is the published page (i dont know how your permission is set up) you can continue to build your source and recreate content in all three target sites.